# Insert Table Names in JComboBox in swing java

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

Well, I am trying to insert name of tables from the database, of a particular user into the JComboBox. I am using a vector to insert the names.

The problem that I'm facing is: When I'm writing the following code:

```
  rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, null, new String[] {"TABLE"});
  while(rs.next())
  {
     System.out.println(rs.getString(3)); 
  }
```

It's running fine! and giving all the table names of all schemas.

But when I'm writing this code:

```
        dbmd = con.getMetaData();

        rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "UserName" , null , new String[] {"TABLE"});
        while((rs.next()) && (rs!=null))
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            tableNames.add(rs.getString(3));
        }
        System.out.println("Hello --- after rs.next()");
        jcb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(tableNames));
        jcb.addItemListener(this);
        add(jcb);
```

---

I'm getting nothing, neither at the console nor on the JComboBox. Please point out the mistake that I'm doing. 
I am sorry, if this question has already been posted but I tried a lot searching those 'already posted questions' but couldn't find the desired answer. That's why I posted my own question. Please don't close or avoid the discussion. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a simple running program that reproduces the issue so we can test it out.